# Add events in UI Calendar on click in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I Am Trying to add events on calendar cell click in Angular 1.5.8.
Angular [UI Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) uses FullCalendar.js through Directive, there is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644308/add-events-in-fullcalender-on-click) of FullCallendar.js for add event on click but its not working in Angular so can canyon please help how to implement this in Angular.

Here's My Code :

`$scope.uiConfig = {
   calendar : {
    height : 500,
    editable : true,
    displayEventTime : false,
    select: function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    },
    eventClick: function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
)};`

`eventClick` is Working Perfectly but normal `select` method is not work and does'nt show any error.

Comment: what is not working? Please show some code and the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace select to dayClick.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
   calendar : {
    height : 500,
    editable : true,
    displayEventTime : false,
    dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
        console.log('test ok ');
    },
    eventClick: function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
)};
```

Its working fine for me.... :-)